# How to make multiple, but separate AJAX calls in JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-templates

I am trying to make 2 separate AJAX calls using buttons. What I want to happen is: when Button1 is clicked ProductsTable shows data from the webservice; when Button2 is clicked OthersTable shows its own data from the webservice. But right now, when either button is clicked, nothing shows up. I know the code works if there's only one of them and it's not wrapped around a .click function.

No error messages. ASP.NET 4.0, JQuery 1.4.4. Not using ScriptManager. Not using UpdatePanels.

Code below:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script id="ProductsTemplate" type="text/x-query-tmpl">
    <tables id="ProductsTemplate">            
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{each d}}
                {{tmpl($value) '#ProductsRowTemplate'}}
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>         
    </tables>
</script>
<script id="ProductsRowTemplate" type="text/x-query-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td>${title}</td>
        <td>${size}</td>
        <td>${price}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script id="Products2Template" type="text/x-query-tmpl">
    <tables id="Products2Template">            
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{each d}}
                {{tmpl($value) '#Products2RowTemplate'}}
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>         
    </tables>
</script>
<script id="Products2RowTemplate" type="text/x-query-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td>${title}</td>
        <td>${size}</td>
        <td>${price}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JSON-WebService.asmx/getProducts",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#ProductsTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#ProductsTable');
                    alert("Products works");
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert("Products didn't work");
                }
            });
        });

        $("#Button2").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JSON-WebService.asmx/getProducts",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#Products2Template').tmpl(data).appendTo('#OthersTable');
                    alert("Products2 works");
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert("Products2 didn't work");
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
<title>Using JQuery</title>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="ProductsTable">

</div>

<div id="OthersTable">

</div>

<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Products" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Products2" />
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: this is weird , we can have as many ajax reqeusts in a page, i think there is something wrong on the back end, can you watch the results in firebug .net panel or have a break point in the backend

Comment: The request is coming through after I click, but that's all I can tell from it. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: what does your rendered HTML look like for those buttons?

Comment: <div>
        <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Products" id="Button1" />
        <input type="submit" name="Button2" value="Products2" id="Button2" />
</div>

Comment: Ok. I found out that that the ASP:Button was causing a postback/reload right after the ajax call. So it looked like nothing was being added. The answer is use $('#Button1').Click(function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); .... ajax code .... });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found out that that the ASP:Button was causing a postback/reload right after the ajax call. So it looked like nothing was being added. The answer is use:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "JSON-WebService.asmx/getProducts",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ProductsTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#ProductsTable');
                alert("Products works");
            },
            failure: function (data) {
                alert("Products didn't work");
            }
        });
    });
 });
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following function that I've written

```
    function jqajax(urlp,thediv) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: urlp,
            dataType: "html",
            //data: "header=variable",
            success: function(data){
                if($('#'+thediv)) 
                {

                  $("#"+thediv).html(data);

                } 
                else 
                {

                  $("#"+thediv).parent().html(data);
                }
            }
          }); 
}
```

to use it you can

> onclick="jqajax(yoururlhere,returnedhtml_div_here);"

Answer (score 0):

As I said watch the .net panel and see if the results are coming for the clicks. If they are coming you have some bug in the html code.

Just remove your binding and alert the complete and see if it prints.Then you can easily print.

Use firebug, .net panel, you can easily fix the problem.